# Why does every compiler see this constructor call as a function pointer?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

My code has a more complex version of basically this situation:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
    T t;
    int i;

    A(T t)
        : t(t)
    {
    }
};

struct S {
};

int main()
{
    A<S> a(S());
    std::cout << a.i << std::endl; // this line does not compile
    return 0;
}
```

I am running into an error which is on every compiler I tried (Clang, GCC and MSVC). Specifically, GCC says:

> request for member ‘i’ in ‘a’, 
>   which is of non-class type ‘A(S (*)())’

Why is this `S (*)()` even mentioned? Looks like despite I declared `S` as a `struct` a bunch of lines above, it sees it as a function pointer or something. Why are all the compilers confused by this? How can `A<S>` suddenly be a non-class type because a misinterpreted constructor call? And why is the error not on the constructor call but on the access of `.i`?

P.S. - The fix can be achieved in many different ways:

`A<S> a(S{});`

`A<S> a{S()};`

`A<S> a{S{}};`

`auto a = A<S>(S());`

So please keep in mind the question is not about the fix, but the reason for the compiler confusion.

Comment: Also see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: `A<S> a(S());` declares a function called `a` that has the return type`A<S>` and it's argument is a function pointer to a function with no argument that returns an `S` (`S(*)()`).